# How to move the below div into right side?

Tags: html, css

```
           <div class="SNS">
                      <ul>
                          <li>
                            <a href="https://twitter.com">
                              <img src="img/Twitter.jpg" alt="Twitter icon" width="20" height="20">
                            </a>
                          </li>
                          
                        </ul>
                </div>
```

I want to set up the twitter logo in the right side of my practice html doc with CSS

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to add the "float: right" attribute to the element using CSS. (either by using the HTML style attribute or using CSS directly)

Here's a good reference for additional help aligning elements with CSS: [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div class="SNS">
                      <ul>
                      
                          <li style="float:right"> <!--Change here-->
                          
                            <a href="https://twitter.com">
                              <img src="twitter.png" alt="Twitter icon" width="20" height="20">
                            </a>
                          </li>
                          
                        </ul>
                </div>
```